# What does "to localize svg" mean?

Tags: html, web, svg, graphics, vector-graphics

I was reading about the SVG from MDN.

I found this description where it says
"SVG-format vector images can be rendered at any size without loss of quality and can be easily ***localized*** by updating the text within them, without the need of a graphical editor to do so"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "swapping out the text for some other language" so that people in, say, Russia, can be given the same graphic, but with text they can read. Rather than, say, Kiswahili text.

You just open it in a text editor, and replace the text, then save it as yourfile.ru.svg or something so you know that's now the Russian version. Or even easier, you write your SVG with a simple templating language so you can generate all your various SVG files for all the languages you want to support with a simple tool run.